# Find Status of LED on coffee maker using Arduino?

Tags: python, arduino

I'm new to the Arduino platform and i'm wondering if it is possible to tell if an LED is on using an arduino input? I'm confused as to if i can check the voltage of one side of the LED in reference to the Arduino's ground? or would i have to check the voltage relative to the other terminal of the LED.
Just a little confused.

Answer (score 1):

This question is probably better asked on electronics.SE, but here goes:

Yes, it is possible, and there are a couple of ways you could do this:

- You could hook up a light sensor to your arduino, aim it at the led, and read that. No modification of the coffee maker is needed
- You could connect a wire to a coffee maker LED, and connect it to Arduino.  But where to connect the wire?  To understand this you have to consider how LEDs are usually hooked up: there is the control signal, the LED itself, a current-limiting diode, and ground. The two main options look like this:

[image]

Assuming that the control voltage is either +5 or zero volts, and assuming your arduino runs on that (and not 3.3V, for example), in both cases (the one on the left and the one on the right), you want to connect your wire to the point indicated as "control".  In the left hand case is "before" the resistor, but in the right hand case it is "before" the LED. You should use your multimeter to confirm your assumptions about the LED circuit, and verify that the connection point indeed is either at +5V and 0v (or whatever your expected voltages are) when the LED is on or off, respectively (if you don't have a multimeter, then this might not be a good project for you)

Comment: Several issues. I have done this many times. But on low voltage equipment. Where recently I tried this on a Dryer an found problems. First, Voltmeter out your LED's both across the + and -. But also to Ground. I found the dryer's LED's were 110 and relative -127dc to ground. All bad for tying to a micro. Consumable electronics take extreme cost savings. 2nd because of the later, most LED's are now multiplexed driven, taking advantage of Persistence of Vision. which may appear on a voltmeter as somewhere between full and off, an oscilloscope may be necessary.

Comment: 3rd be cautious not to violate safety, on anything above 24Vdc, which a coffee maker at 110/220Vac is. It should have some safety approval like UL, CSA, NRTL, TUV, etc... Another way is to use a kill-a-watt to meter the power and then have the arduino react. On my Dryer I actual did something similar to http://www.ladyada.net/make/tweetawatt/ but replaced the Xbee with a Arduino, button and buzzer. so the Arduino had a state machine. and not her hack is on the low voltage section, not the hi-pot.

Comment: @mpflaga: In your 110V case, it probably wasn't a LED, but rather a lamp. I was assuming that when OP said "LED" that's indeed what it was.

Comment: strange thing was the PCB's was label with diode symbol and indicating + and -, along illuminating that 590nm green. So i was baffled and found the controller and IO board was riddled with -127Vdc. hence my fall back to Kill-A-Watt. My big point is to, First Measure, Scope out and understand what you are about to HACK. Especially if it could burn down your house.

Comment: @mpflaga: Yes, that is hard to disagree with.

Comment: Another point about the light sensor. One needs to block out ambient light. Which can be problematic. Either shield it, which means the operator can't see it. Or may take advantage of it being multixplexed, in which it will appear modulated. Then you can demodulate it, by substracting the ambient background. Using the A2D

Comment: There are a lot of implementation-specific details that we can't know about. Does the LED in question put out specific wavelength where the ambient light might not interfere?  Does the operator need to see it?  We just don't know.